# How to perform row and column filter operations in a csv file in scala

Tags: scala, csv

I am writing scala scripts. I need to perform row filter operations such as greater than,less than operations for the csv file. I have tried using filter option in the script unable to get the results. Please let me know how to perform filter operation for the csv file. The sample data has been attached here for reference.Thanks in advance.

```
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
        cols += line.split(",").filter(csv => csv(1).toInt > 10000)}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd do like this `val cols = bufferedSource.getLines.map(line=>line.split(",")).filter(csv => csv(1).toInt > 10000)`.

Comment: Have you considered using Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resorting to **for** use **map**. This code snippet should work

```
bufferedSource.getLines.map(row => row.split(",")).filter(cols => cols(1).toInt > 10000).toList
```

Also, it's a better approach to use a case class for the CSV you are filtering to make your code more readable.